# Sending additional parameters via form using POST: hidden fields or query parameters

Tags: html

I have some HTML forms and I need to provide additional parameters which the user will not fill up in the form UI. I understand I can do it using query parameters or hidden form fields. Examples :

1. a form whose data must be submitted to the server together with an option chosen in the previous web page

Ex: URL /createImage?option=option_value (accessible via GET by user) would contain the HTML code below

Query parameter

```
<form action='/createImage?option=option_value'>
  <input type='textfield1' name='var1'>
</form>
```

Hidden field

```
<form action='/createImage'>
  <input type='hidden' name='option' value='option_value'>
  <input type='textfield1' name='var1'>
</form>
```

(in this case, I suppose a third solution would be to use a HTTP session variable instead)

2. a fake form used to associate a POST HTTP request with a image.

Query parameter

```
<form action='/createContainer?image=image1'>
  <input type='image' src='container.png'>
</form>
```

Hidden field

```
<form action='/createContainer'>
  <input type='hidden' name='image' value='image1'>
  <input type='image' src='container.png'>
</form>
```

(in this case, I suppose a third solution would be to use a standard img HTML tag and use Javascript to send the POST request to the server on its click() event)

Are there any upsides/downsides in each one of those approaches or is it just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: Recommended how? All approaches work. Perfectly common to store URL-arriving data in hidden inputs and then pass it along to the next URL (i.e. the form action).

Comment: I want to know if there are any downsides and upsides in both solutions, I'll make it clearer in my question.